# How to work with large numbers with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, types

I'm creating script for automated testing of financial application.

Using VbScript as language.

Need to manipulate with large floating point numbers (more than 10 billions) - make add, multiply operations and so on. But vbscript doesn't have data type for large numbers.

Please, advise me any solution or workaround for this problem.

Maybe someone had faced  with this problem before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBScript has some data types for large numbers. In your case, you probably want to use Double.
Here's an overview: http://www.csidata.com/custserv/onlinehelp/vbsdocs/vbs0.htm

Comment: If it's so serious that it deserves a Caps Lock, can you please tell us why?

Comment: @ulu  see my response to this question below. Basically the typical "float" and "double" types store your number as raw binary data. There are numbers in base 10 with an exact base 10 representation have a repeating binary representation (e.g. 0.1d -> 0.000110011...b); these repeating fractions get rounded, and that rounding causes errors that add up materially when you have lots of operations (transactions). "currency" types are stored as base 10 (decimal) numbers and therefore fix this (trade off is they are larger and slower). "Real" accounting/tax/finance software must use currency types.

Answer (score 1):

@Rob's link is good but his selection of data type is dangerous. Use the Currency type as it is represented internally by a fixed point number.

If you need more than 4 decimal points then you are facing either:

- a need to change languages (Java, C# and others support data types with names like BigDecimal that are suitable and may have better precision)
- a need to write a custom library which I strongly advise against (it needs to be watertight or else you're still mangling your data).

Binary floating point numbers cannot represent decimal numbers accurately and you can end up with rounding errors that make your data invalid. See [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) if you want details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the decimal data type:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: I don't think VBScript has that data type... your link describes Visual Basic datatypes, not VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```
function mmod(a,moduloValue)
  dim k,t
  k=CDbl(a)
  t=Fix(k/moduloValue)
  mmod = k-(t*moduloValue)
end function

msgbox mmod(4010051786300000078934,1024)
```

output: 86

```
msgbox mmod(4010051786300000078934,2)
```

output: 0

Comment: thanks for the answer. You can format your code by selecting it in the editor and pressing Control-K (or clicking the little 10010 button).

Comment: Its unclear what this function is supposed to do. Because this is only one function it cannot possibly do everything that has been asked for. But most importantly I notice that the argument a is converted to floating point and... NEVER USE FLOATING POINT NUMBERS FOR FINANCIAL DATA!!!!!

Comment: I know this is an old post, but how do you DISPLAY very large numbers in classic ASP?  They all seem to convert to E notation, very annoying!